# do while loop not performing as expected

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I am creating an oregon trail clone as a proof of concept type thing, and for some reason the loop of the function I determined before int main isn't looping, and just not doing anything.

```
using namespace std;
int debuginput;
string response;
int loop = 0;
void commands ()
{
  if (response == "cmd")
    {
      cout <<
    "what would you like to do? type 'help' to get a list of commands." <<
    endl;
      cin >> response;
      if (response == "start")
    {
      loop = 1;
    }
      else
    {
      loop = 0;
    }
      if (response == "test")
    {
      cout << "test";
    }
    }
}

int
main ()
{
 cin >> response;
  do
    {
      commands ();
    }
  while (loop == 0);
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
}
```

Basically, whenever I call the **commands** function to loop, I enter one command and it doesn't loop to let me put in another command.

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Looks like you need to reorder the comparisons.

Comment: Your program will take commands multiple times provided that the command you enter is `cmd`. When your program is running and the CPU usage is low, your program is probably waiting for input.

Comment: Analysing the logical structure of your code would be easier if you got rid of as many global variables as you can. I get the impression that you are unaware of function parameters....

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski The **local** `loop` variable is set to `1` and it won't affect the loop.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. If I had to debug this code, the very first thing I would do is remove everything but 1-2 lines of code that let me observe if the loop is executed or not

Comment: @MikeCAT right, got lost in the indentation :P

Comment: Ah, @Yunnosch I forgot about those, I did simplify my code though with the same error, though. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code inside your `commands` function:

```
if (response == "start") {
   int loop = 1;
}
```

you create a new variable with name loop on the stack, set it to 1 and then it immediately gets destroyed. You shadow the global variable `loop` with this.

I assume the correct variant would be:

```
if (response == "start") {
   loop = 1;
}
```

If you type in `start` it will update the `loop` variable and then the `do while` loop will end. If this is not what you want you should change the condition like that:

```
void commands() {
    // ...
    cin >> response;
    if (response == "start") {
        loop = 1;
    } else {
        loop = 0;
    }
}

do {
    commands();
} while (loop == 1);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that guarantee that the loop ends?

Comment: My compiler auto-connects things like if and else statements and brackets, hence the indentation as it doesn't carry over into text.

Comment: Also, even if that fixes my start, it won't repeat when not continuing.

Comment: @flying, please, take a look at the updated answer. Maybe it will be of some help.

Comment: It improved the code, *but* it still won't loop. I will edit this with a more simplified version of the code.